# Apache serving some images with html content

Tags: php, html, image, apache

So I come in to work today to find that some of my images aren't being served into the `img` elements properly. The path is fine and the requests are returning `200` but the images themselves are blank.

When I open the image address directly in the browser (ie: `http://www.example.com/images/image.png`, the page loads with a bunch of unstyled html as if I had requested a page, not an image. The html is from pages related to the image, but there is nowhere in that request that I am specifying a page. It's as if the image is being served as an html document instead of an image. Is this a server setting or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had some dodgy rewrite rules in my `.htaccess` file which was matching part of the string of the image filename, and internally redirecting to a page but serving it all messed up because of my dodgy `.htaccess`. Solved the problem by making the `.htaccess` rules more regulated.